# Allow a user to access a single Git repository

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, git

Consider a server that hosts several Git repositories:

```
$ ls -l /opt/git/
drwxrwxr-x 7 ubuntu root   4096 Jan  2  2014 george.git
drwxrwxr-x 7 ubuntu root   4096 Dec 29  2013 john.git
drwxrwsr-x 7 ubuntu root   4096 Jul  4  2013 paul.git
drwxrwsr-x 7 ubuntu root   4096 Jun 30  2013 ringo.git
```

Until now, all developers had access to all the Git repos via SSH. I am now adding a dev who should only have access to the `john.git` repo. I've created a Linux user `yoko` but I'm not sure how I should let `yoko` access the `/opt/git/john.git` directory in the safest manner without letting him access the other directories in `/opt/git/`.

**What is the canonical way of restricting access as such?**

My inclination is to make the `john.git` as group `foobar` and add that group to user `yoko`'s groups. However, what happens if I later need to add another user that could access two repos? For instance, I might want to add user `cynthia` with access to both `john.git` and to `paul.git`. **Should I have a separate group for each Git repo?** I could see that getting unwieldy very quickly

Note that these users should have access to **nothing** other than their own `/home/user/` directories and additionally to the Git repo(s) that they are permitted. If there is a way to symlink i.e. `/home/yoko/john.git` to `/opt/git/john.git` in a way that prevents access to the rest of `/opt/git/` that would be best, however I cannot seem to configure the system as such.

The server is running Ubuntu Server 12.04 but I could possibly update it to 14.04 if there is need. The users connect via SSH using RSA keys, no password. They will be performing `git pull` and `git push` on the server, nothing more.

Comment: You should look at gitolite or gitlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small number of repos, the groups approach works just fine.  Yes, each repo potentially needs its own group, and it does get unwieldy if you've got more repos.  As @AlexeyTen mentioned in the comments, if you have a larger number of repos, or would like a more "high-level" management interface, you should look at a repo manager like gitolite or gitlab.  Gitolite is managed via text files in a git repo (config files and SSH keys are committed to a special git repo and pushed, and everything is configured).  Gitlab, on the other hand, is an all-in-one webapp similar in concept to a self-hosted Github.  If you don't need all the bells and whistles, gitolite will almost certainly do the job perfectly.